# transactional file append on windows

Tags: .net, file, winapi, io, transactions

I have a simple operation to perform: quickly append a tiny piece of data to large file residing on NTFS. The additional requirement is that it has to be done atomically. There are, however, no requirements on concurrency (one writer, no readers).

How can I approach the problem? References to .NET API or WinAPI are most welcome.

Conceptually this should be easy to achieve: just write the data and then atomically write file size (at most 64-bit number). Using a database seems to be an overkill - especially given that I should keep compatibility with existing on disk format and change the existing code as little as possible.

Comment: Your solution seems very good. You also could append chunks with a cryptographic checksum at the end. When reading only process chunks that have a valid checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional NTFS has been deprecated (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363764(v=vs.85).aspx) and I suspect it will be gone completely soon.

These leaves other transactional stores such as databases.

Comment: Yes, but the databases have to achieve this functionality somehow.

Comment: The amount of work you'd need to do to implement this would be far more overkill than using a database, but if you are interested then this has been a question on stackoverflow before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365401/how-do-database-vendors-implement-transactions

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny There's only a single instance of the server. The server process manages contention, serializes transactions and so on. You could reinvent this wheel if you like, but why would you choose to do so?

Comment: @David Heffernan: you have clearly not read my question: I have no issue with concurrency, but I do have issue with compatibility.

Comment: @Ananke: seems to me that WAL solves a problem one layer up - my problem is precisely how to write a log/journal in a safe manner.

Comment: @David Heffernan - don't try to make a fool of yourself. I have no readers at the time of writing (between first write and process finish), possibly never, but the data needs to be there and be consistent.

Comment: So why do you think that it won't be there? You are concerned about partial writes due to machine failure? Perhaps you should make this clear. Please also stop being abusive.